# joining two tables and finding the sum of marks for each student

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

i have two tables of results, a mid-term result table and annual result table.

**Mid-term result table:**
[image]

**Annual result table:**

[image]

i want to join them and find the total marks of each student for each subject

**wanted result table after finding the total marks of mid-term and terminal result[image]**

**my code so far:**

```
mysql_query("drop view if exists result_view");
mysql_query("create view result_view as 
           select * from mid_term
            UNION ALL
           select * from annual") or die(mysql_error());

//now find the total marks of students for each subject
mysql_query("select id,student_id,subject_id,result_id,year,sum(mark) as mark
              from result_view ");
```

but this does not work out, any help or advice plz!!!!!!1

Comment: yap, dat was a mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think id field make much sense in the result so I omitted it.

```
SELECT   Student_id, 
         Subject_id, 
         Result_id, 
         year,
         SUM(mark)
    FROM result_view
GROUP BY Student_id, 
         Subject_id, 
         Result_id,
         year
```

Answer (score 0):

You need GROUP BY:

```
select id, student_id, subject_id,result_id,year,sum(mark) as TotalMark
from result_view
GROUP BY id, student_id, subject_id, result_id, year
```

See my [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d89cf/1)

Comment: @internally1 See my Fiddle Demo.

Answer (score 0):

By presuming result_id for both the table remains same, Try

```
SELECT m.id,m.student_id,m.subject_id,m.result_id,m.year,(m.mark+a.mark) AS mark
FROM mid_term m, annual a
WHERE m.result_id=a.result_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select t1.id,t1.student_id,t1.subject_id,t1.year,
    t1.result_id,t1.mark+t2.mark as marks from table t1 
    inner join table t2 on t1.id=t2.id 
    order by t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this

```
SELECT
    mt.id,
    mt.student_id,
    mt.subject_id,
    mt.result_id,
    mt.year,
    (mt.mark + ar.mark) marks
FROM mid_term mt
LEFT JOIN annual ar 
ON ar.student_id = mt.student_id
AND ar.result_id = mt.result_id
AND ar.year = mt.year
AND ar.subject_id = mt.subject_id
GROUP BY mt.student_id,mt.subject_id
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d89cf/9)

Output

```
| ID | STUDENT_ID | SUBJECT_ID |     RESULT_ID | YEAR | MARKS |
|----|------------|------------|---------------|------|-------|
|  1 |      Stud1 |         PH | Stud1/PH/2013 | 2013 |   100 |
|  2 |      Stud1 |         CH | Stud1/CH/2013 | 2013 |    99 |
|  3 |      Stud2 |         PH | Stud2/PH/2013 | 2013 |   100 |
|  4 |      Stud2 |         CH | Stud2/CH/2013 | 2013 |   100 |
```